# Multiple WSL2 instances with different Apache2 ports

Tags: apache-http-server, port, wsl2

I'm trying to run two WSL2 instances, as I thought it would be a nice and clean way to work on multiple websites at once which have different system requirements.

##### I am trying to achieve:

- WSL Instance 1, runs website A, php7.2, under apache on port 80
- WSL Instance 2, runs website B, php8.1, under apache on port 8081

Both websites should be able to load in a browser at the same time locally.

The problem is that when I have both wsl2 instances running under port 80 Website A redirects to Website B in the browser. So I tried to have apache on WSL Instance 2 run on port 8081 by doing the following:

1. Add the following line in /etc/apache2/ports.conf:

> Listen 8081

2. Changed Website B's config file to look like this:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:8081>

   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

   ServerName magento.local

   ServerAlias magento.local

   DocumentRoot /var/www/magento2/pub

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   <Directory "/var/www">

   AllowOverride all

   </Directory>

   </VirtualHost>
   ```

When I do that though, both Website A and Website B load the default apache2 index.html page.

If this problem can be solved in a more elegant way (without editing ports) that allows me to achieve running both websites simultaneously, that would be great too. I'm not a server person might have gone down the wrong rabbit hole with respect to ports.

Comment: You've told apache to listen on 8080 but the virtualhost is on 8081. This will not work. Set bot ports.conf and the virtualhost to the same port instead.

Comment: Why don’t you just create a single Apache configuration with multiple virtual hosts?

Comment: @Ramhound You cannot run apache with different PHP versions.

Comment: @mashuptwice - It was possible in [2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033511/how-to-select-php-version-5-and-7-per-virtualhost-in-apache-2-4-on-debian)

Comment: @Ramhound good to know, thanks for sharing.